# increase and creating empty image boxs , till the number is even

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well actually i don't know how to ask this, I have an object which stores the image path from database and it was shown like a category on my page, each role having 4 images.

It looks great if the object length is an even number, like 4, but in case of odd numbers it looks weird, so I decided to add an empty image box to it when the object length is odd.

But how do I start? I have no idea, something like this:

```
box = 7 now (which is a odd);

var checkCategoryNumber = function (box){
  if (box.length % 2 == 0) {
    // do noting
    alert("even");
  }
  else {
    // increase and create an empty image box, till the number is even.  
    alert("odd");
  }
}
```

Which will create one empty image box to 8 and it stop.

Hope you understand what I mean, please let me know if the question is confusing, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by empty image box?

Comment: Kenny thank for take a look , making a fake box with css or img contain noting but word said is empty box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if `box` is odd number and if it is add empty box.

```js
var checkCategoryNumber = function(box) {
  for (var i = 0; i < box; i++) {
    $('body').append(i + 1 + '. Box <br>')
  }
  if (box % 2 != 0) $('body').append(box + 1 + '. Empty box <br><hr>')
}
checkCategoryNumber(7)
checkCategoryNumber(6)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```